# Map a custom type to multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to work with a large bitmask (~115 bits). The storage is mysql and my orm is doctrine. On PHP side I wrote a class to handle anything and know I need a good solution to store and find it again by bitcomparing in MySQL. My idea is to use four integer column or two bigints. Now I need a kind of mapping (PHP Object <=> 2-4 Columns DB). Is there something in symfony2 I can use?

Answer (score 0):

This is not done as often. A lot of times there will be single columns with BIT type (or TINYINT on MySQL) or put the options in another table and do a oneToMany (this will allow for your options to be easily configurable). Bitmasks are more error prone so make sure you really want this solution. That being said, this is how it could be done:

First some information on the MySQL datatypes. For bitmasks unsigned is probably the way to go.

```
TINYINT -> 0-255 = 256 combinations = log 256 / log 2 = 8 bits
SMALLINT -> 16 bits
MEDIUMINT -> 24 bits
INT -> 32 bits
BIGINT -> 64 int
```

So what is your optimal usage of these fields for 115 bits? This is a NP-complete problem and you could use the Greedy Algorithm. Taking your suggestion and go with 4x INT and 2x BIGINT. Gives me 256 available bits in total. This is above your requirement of 115 bits. And using 4x BIGINT for 256 bits would make more sense. However i can not merge these columns into one big number and also BIGINT's might even be problematic. As stated in the PHP manual:

```
The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.
```

For safety (because i don't know your platform) i will make only use INT and use four of them to give me 128 bits. (You will still need to check how this would work on a 32 bits problem which doesn't support the unsigned integer!)

This is a default function that doctrine:generate:Entities would give you: `public function getColumn1() {}` However it doesn't seem like a good idea to give your other objects access to this raw unprocessed data. So let's make custom functions for this.

```
private function getBit($index) {
    if (0 <= $index AND $index <= 31) {
        return ($this->column1 >> $index) & 1;
    } elseif (32 <= $index AND $index <= 63) {
        $index -= 32;
        return ($this->column2 >> $index) & 1;
    } elseif (64 <= $index AND $index <= 95) {
        $index -= 64;
        return ($this->column3 >> $index) & 1;
    } elseif (96 <= $index AND $index <= 127) {
        $index -= 96;
        return ($this->column4 >> $index) & 1;
    }
}

private function setBit($index, $value) {
    if (! is_bool($value)) \BadMethodCallException('value needs to be a boolean'); // A form of type checking to make the interface to the function more clearly
    $value = (int)$value; // not sure if this is needed, just to make sure

    if (0 <= $index AND $index <= 31) {
        $this->column1 = ($this->column1 & ~(1 << $index)) | ($value << $index);
    } elseif (32 <= $index AND $index <= 63) {
        $index -= 32;
        $this->column2 = ($this->column2 & ~(1 << $index)) | ($value << $index);
    } elseif (64 <= $index AND $index <= 95) {
        $index -= 64;
        $this->column3 = ($this->column3 & ~(1 << $index)) | ($value << $index);
    } elseif (96 <= $index AND $index <= 127) {
        $index -= 96;
        $this->column4 = ($this->column4 & ~(1 << $index)) | ($value << $index);
    }
}
```

Column1 is for the Least Significant Bits, additional columns add more Most Significant Bits. Now that we have our low level functions in place to handle the raw bits, it will be easy to use normal getters and settings for the properties you want.

```
public function setFlag4($value) {
    $this->setBit(4, $value);
    return $this;
}

public function getFlag4() {
    return $this->getBit(4);
}
```

Of course instead of Flag4 you can type any name like `hasBananas()` on bit 25

Comment: Thank you Flip. The mapping which bit belongs to which integer is not the problem. I'm looking for a lightweight, transparent doctrine solution like the DateTime-mapping, but in this case one object needs multiple colums.

Comment: I can say with near 100% certainty that there isn't a native Doctrine solution for this. Also it's unlikely that many people would be interested in making this. So this is as good as it gets. You could however decide to take this solution (or another one) and write your own Doctrine extensions. If this answer was helpful to you, please accept my answer.